# What the voicing of air from a mouth called?

Tags: word-request

What the voicing of air from a mouth (without syllable) called? 
For example when we say the consonant "sh"  without  a syllable. It's usually happens when you want to quiet a child  or something like that (it's almost like a whistling, but it's not exactly the same, or maybe it's a kind of whistling). In some cultures when one wonders on somethings bad or huge he may make such sound. I'm looking for the name for this sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you mean.  When you say "shh" to someone to quiet them, that's called "shushing."  When you emit voiceless white noise from your mouth like an H sound, that's called "hissing."

Comment: Thank you. It seems this is the answer I looked for. Due to using your word 'hissing' I could find some cultures who use it for expression of negative emotion.  For example: https://www.japanintercultural.com/en/news/default.aspx?newsID=73. And also here: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=zSDsCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT6724&dq=hiss+BIBLE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPo_PI4JvkAhUuxosKHU_jA-QQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=hiss%20BIBLE&f=false